# Download speed measures below ISP rated speed

Tags: windows-7, internet, download

My internet connection is advertised to be 10 MBps or around 1 MB/s. I normally get download speeds up to 1 MB/s or no less than 750 KB/s but now it's down to not much higher than 150 KB/s and around 300 - 350 KB/s if I'm lucky

Note:

- There are no background programs hogging up my bandwidth
- Happened recently
- Seems that it doesn't matter what site I download from
- P2P speeds are fine
- Avast Free Edition isn't blocking anything
- Windows Firewall is turned off
- Didn't happen until I reinstalled a week ago
- Upload speed is fine
- ISP is [Distributel](http://distributel.com)

Comment: Who is your ISP and what does http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/ tell you?

Comment: My ISP is Distributel

Comment: You *may* very well be having technical issues.  However, for home users, network bandwidth is not guaranteed by ISPs.  Call your ISP and ask them to test the circuit.

Comment: Well a quick google search shows that Distributel is throttling, seems to be a regional thing and only on torrents. I would call them up and see whats going on.

Comment: Weird. With good seeds, my torrent downloads such as eclipse and ubuntu are usually faster and more stable than regular downloads

Comment: By faster I mean like avg speeds of up to 1.1 MB/s and sometimes it jumps to 1.5-1.6 MB/s for short time periods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to TekSavvy and haven't had a problem for months. Turns out Distributel isn't so good in my area

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that your bandwidth is being throttled by your internet provider. If you frequently download heavy loads or you frequent sites that are suspected of providing legally-questionable content your provider may be zapping your allotted bandwidth. You can call your ISP to ask them about this. Comcast in VA throttled my entire building once many years ago and only took off the restrictions when we called them several times to complain.

Furthermore, I suggest you contact your local and state legislators and demand they stand up and fight for net-neutrality.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up your units. 1 megabit, a common DSL circuit speed, is about 125 kilobytes per second download. Circuit speeds are typically measured in bits while download speeds as reported by your browser are typically in bytes.

Comment: I have 10 Mbps cable and that's = to 1.25 MB/s and around 800 KB/s - 1.1 MB/s was what my download speeds were originally

Comment: Then your next step is to bypass your router and plug a single computer into your cable modem. Run a speed test. Run a continuous ping to your ISP's primary DNS for an hour or two and look for loss, latency or jitter. If you see anything erroneous then call up the ISP and present your findings. These are the same tests they will have you do if you call them up, so you might as well do them first.